# Getting the Value of a CPP Object using IDA Pro and IDAPython

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, ida

I've set a breakpoint using IDA Pro on a function that returns a cocos2d::Image object pointer as a response, as can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image: IDA Breakpoint]

However, I'm at a complete loss at how I can use IDAPython to print out the Object members, and such. Is there a way to do it? The Docs haven't been too helpful, and only seem to have methods to check for C-like structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print Dword(addr)` for printing dword-sized members and `print Byte(addr)` for printing byte-sized members. `Result` is stored in `eax`, so you can use
relative offsets from `eax` to get member addresses. To print all the members from the screenshot that will be:

```
eaxVal = GetRegValue("eax")
print Dword(eaxVal+45)
print "\n"
print Dword(eaxVal+51)
print "\n"
print Dword(eaxVal+52)
print "\n"
print Byte(eaxVal+184)
print "\n"
print Byte(eaxVal+188)
print "\n"
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I did figure it out a while after I posted my question, and I've been using the exact same method as yourself.